# Autoload dos Models no Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel

Boa noite
Gostaria de saber se no Laravel 5.1 existe uma forma de se fazer autoload, tanto nos Models como nos Controllers?
No Laravel 4 para se criar uma instância de um Model, bastava chamar o Model, dessa forma:

```
$user = new User();
```

Mas pelo que percebi no Laravel 5, precisa colocar o caminho do Model no controller.

Comment: Já tentou rodar  `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: No laravel 5 é preciso chamar pelo namespace p.x: App\Models\User;! A menos que você crie um aliás no app.php. É possível também fazer o class map pelo composer, psr-4

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que utilizar `use` e o caminho para as `models ou controllers`,

exemplo:

Arquivo ProdutoController.php, estou pegando a model Produto assim:

```
 use app\Produto;
```

Answer (score 1):

O autoload continua ali, só depende como vc quer chamar a classe

**Normal**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class UsersController extends App\Http\Controllers\Controller {

    public function create() {
        $user = new App\User;
    }

}
```

Ou criando uma alias

**Aliasing**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;

class UsersController extends Controller {

    public function create() {
        $user = new User();
    }

}
```

Para revisar dar uma revisada no básico do laravel 5, recomendo ver
https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals
é grátis.

Comment: Então, mas na versão 4 você nao precisava colocar "use App\User" para cada Model que fosse chamar. É isso que queria saber sacou? Se tem alguma maneira de não precisar colocar isso